# Rest Api post using Postman Chrome Extension

Tags: rest, google-chrome, post, get, postman

I am using postman to check GET and POST using rest api, I am setting header : Content-Type to application/json.

Please see the attached images, What am I missing during post I am successfully getting response from GET:
Image links:
Post: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz2yzzoSJQWeUGFxU2UwSlNRT00/view?usp=sharing
Get: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz2yzzoSJQWeQnZBY0FOSEpfTjg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you're getting html for the post.
Looks like you're using url/method not supported by this API.

In my case that was the reason. Try to dig this direction.

Comment: Are you referring to content type I am getting the GET output in JSON so I am using the   content type:application/json in post

Comment: I double checked I am using the same url for both get and post,if it works for Get then the same url should hold true for Post right? please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: It should work only if the POST method is supported by your web service for this url

Comment: Ok so the problem lies there, Thankyou

Comment: Don't you mind to accept the answer if it worths that